# Improving sort array by child array value

Tags: php

I am trying to sort my array by a child array value, and I am using this with `uasort`, but the code is ugly and looks like it could have been done better, since there's a lot of duplicate code.

How can I improve this switch/case sort I've build?

```
switch ($this->view->sort_key_num) {
  case 1: // Date
      if ($this->view->sort_key_type == 1)
        krsort($this->view->content);
    break;
  case 2: // Likes
    function sort_like(&$a, &$b) { return ($a['likes'] > $b['likes']) ? 1 : -1; }
    uasort($this->view->content, 'sort_like');
    if ($this->view->sort_key_type == 1)
      $this->view->content = array_reverse($this->view->content);
    break;
  case 3: // new content
    function sort_entries(&$a, &$b) { return ($a['newcontent'] > $b['newcontent']) ? 1 : -1; }
    uasort($this->view->content, 'sort_entries');
    if ($this->view->sort_key_type == 1)
      $this->view->content = array_reverse($this->view->content);
    break;
  case 4: // comments
    function sort_comments(&$a, &$b) { return ($a['comments'] > $b['comments']) ? 1 : -1; }
    uasort($this->view->content, 'sort_comments');
    if ($this->view->sort_key_type == 1)
      $this->view->content = array_reverse($this->view->content);
    break;
  case 5: // facebook
    function sort_facebook(&$a, &$b) { return ($a['facebook'] > $b['facebook']) ? 1 : -1; }
    uasort($this->view->content, 'sort_facebook');
    if ($this->view->sort_key_type == 1)
      $this->view->content = array_reverse($this->view->content);
    break;
  case 6: // twitter
    function sort_twitter(&$a, &$b) { return ($a['twitter'] > $b['twitter']) ? 1 : -1; }
    uasort($this->view->content, 'sort_twitter');
    if ($this->view->sort_key_type == 1)
      $this->view->content = array_reverse($this->view->content);
    break;
  case 7: // email
    function sort_email(&$a, &$b) { return ($a['email'] > $b['email']) ? 1 : -1; }
    uasort($this->view->content, 'sort_email');
    if ($this->view->sort_key_type == 1)
      $this->view->content = array_reverse($this->view->content);
    break;
  case 8: // google
    function sort_google(&$a, &$b) { return ($a['google'] > $b['google']) ? 1 : -1; }
    uasort($this->view->content, 'sort_google');
    if ($this->view->sort_key_type == 1)
      $this->view->content = array_reverse($this->view->content);
    break;
  case 10: // views
    function sort_views(&$a, &$b) { return ($a['views'] > $b['views']) ? 1 : -1; }
    uasort($this->view->content, 'sort_views');
    if ($this->view->sort_key_type == 1)
      $this->view->content = array_reverse($this->view->content);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done all the test cases nor read them all in detail but i think this would be a good optimization of your code...

```
class customSorter {
    private $sortCrit = NULL;
    public function __construct($criteria){
            $this->sortCrit = $criteria;
    }
    public function sort(&$a, &$b) { return ($a[$this->sortCrit] > $b[$this->sortCrit]) ? 1 : -1; }
}

switch ($this->view->sort_key_num) {
    case 1: // Date
        if ($this->view->sort_key_type == 1){
            krsort($this->view->content);
        }
        break;

    case 2: // Likes
        uasort($this->view->content, array(new customSorter('likes'), 'sort'));
        break;

    case 3: // new content
        uasort($this->view->content, array(new customSorter('newcontent'), 'sort'));
        break;

    case 4: // comments
        uasort($this->view->content, array(new customSorter('comments'), 'sort'));
        break;

    case 5: // facebook
        uasort($this->view->content, array(new customSorter('facebook'), 'sort'));
        break;
}

//Reverse the sort?
if ($this->view->sort_key_type == 1){ 
    $this->view->content = array_reverse($this->view->content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class to sort based on a `type`.

```
class Sorter {
    private $type;
    private $content;
    public function __construct($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }
    public function sort($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        uasort($this->content, function ($a,$b) {
            return $b[$this->type] - $a[$this->type];
        });
    }
}
```

Now I've removed the Date part, since that was a special case. Instead, we handle the Date part separately.

```
if ($this->view->sort_key_type == 1 && $this->view->sort_key_num == 1) {
    krsort($this->view->content);
}
```

If it turns out it's not a Date we're working with, we create an instance of the Sorter class that we defined before and feed it your data - notice how this is done by reference.

```
else {
    $sorter = new Sorter(&$this->view->content);
    switch ($this->view->sort_key_num) {
        case 2: $sorter->sort('likes'); break;
        case 3: $sorter->sort('newcontent') break;
        case 4: $sorter->sort('comments'); break;
        case 5: $sorter->sort('facebook'); break;
            ...
    }
}
```

In your old code, you'd reverse your array at the end, but this isn't necessary, since I have reversed your compare method (the one you give to `uasort`), so the code will be sorted in reverse order.

Comment: Becareful though that this code is ran on a 5.3 php server. 5.2 doesn't support closures like this user is suggesting. Nice work though, i'm still stuck in php 5.2 so i didn't think about the closure way. Looks like mine but with a 5.3 savor...

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin Thanks for the hint, wasn't aware that anonymous functions weren't implemented earlier than that.